# help identify a LEGO set from bags

Tags: sets, set-identification

[image: unknown set bag 1]
[image: unknown set bag 2]

Please can you help me identify from what LEGO set these parts bags came?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty sure it's the [9450 Epic Dragon Battle](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=9450-1).

[image: pic]

it has both the Black Bionicle Foot Piraka Clawed in black and the Brick, Round 2 x 2 with Grille in white as well as other notable parts.